# How can I compare objects with each other in an array by their key:value pairs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

So, I am in a bit stuck. I have CSV data, which I have read using node.js' fs() function. I have converted them to objects, pushed them into an array, of which I have filtered down, to return a new array. An array of objects, each object, has a key of interactions, its value, is also an array of objects.

Essentially, the structure of the array I am left to work with looks like this

```
[{ userId: '2439',
  interactions:
   [ { user_Id: '2439',
       job_Id: '3957',
       direction: 'true',
       time: '2019-08-14 11:57:30' },
     { user_Id: '2439',
       job_Id: '3431',
       direction: 'true',
       time: '2019-08-14 11:56:31' } ] },
...]
```

So I would like to find a pair of objects which have the most similarity, meaning they have interactions of which job_id are the same. So let's just say, I take the index above as the point of reference, I use that, and compare it with the next object in the array by ensuring the job_id's are the same within the interactions array. I do this iteratively, until the end. Then I take the next object as the point of reference and do the same.

This is my solution for now

```
let fs = require("fs");

const readFile = () => fs.readFile("./data/reactions.csv", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var dataArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    dataArray.shift();
    mapToObject(dataArray)
});

mapToObject = (data) => {
    let arrayOfObjects = []
    data.forEach(userInformation => {
        let arrayInfo = userInformation.split(",");
        let obj = {
            user_Id: arrayInfo[0],
            job_Id: arrayInfo[1],
            direction: arrayInfo[2],
            time: arrayInfo[3]
        }
        arrayOfObjects.push(obj);
    });
    findUserInteractions(arrayOfObjects);
}

findUserInteractions = (users) => {
    let arrayOfUserInteractions = []
    users.forEach(user => {
        let filterUserIds = users.filter(userObj => userObj.user_Id === user.user_Id)
        let result = filterUserIds.filter(userObj => userObj.direction === "true")
        let newObj = {
            userId: user.user_Id,
            interactions: result
        }
        arrayOfUserInteractions.push(newObj);
    })
    console.log(arrayOfUserInteractions[4]);
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: It's unclear what the question or problem is. It would also be best to limit code to the specifics of the problem, e.g., from the array of data you're working with, rather than tying it up to less-related issues. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Just returns a pair of user_id's that are the most similar in terms of job_ids, taking into consideration how many interactions a user has

Comment: Please provide example input and output. Instead of fs paste minimal viable data.

Comment: "*which have the most similarity*" - can you define that more specifically? There are many [similarity measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure). Do you want to find the pair which have the highest number of shared job ids? Which have the highest fraction of shared job ids? Something else?